# Existing Spring Application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, tomcat, cloud-foundry, ibm-was, xml-configuration

We are planning to move a Spring based application to Cloud Foundry.
The application currently uses WAS server and access data sources using JNDI lookup.
We are using spring features like MVC, AOP etc.
I have certain questions in mind :

1. Is it possible to switch to Tomcat and configure dataSources using Spring-cloud-connectors and possible conflicts we might run into ?
2. Currently , datasources are configured in XML files, Should I use the same XML files or switch to annotations.

Can anyone please provide some clarity over this and other known issues with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Connectors are by far the easiest way to bind to data sources in Cloud Foundry. I would recommend converting your JNDI lookups to use these service connections as described here:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

cloud foundry automatically reconfigures your datasource when it find a database service attached the cloud app. its super coooool....